# How to test multiple method calls with and_yield

Tags: ruby, rspec

After much frustration, I discovered that I have misunderstood how `.and_yield` works and differs from `.and_return`.  Multiple `.and_yield`'s do not yield a different value each time the method that accepts the block is called like multiple `.and_return`'s, but instead yields all the multiple `.and_yield`'s per method call.  this example should better help explain...

```
class Foo
  def self.ask &block
    yield gets.chomp
  end
end

describe Foo do
  it 'should enforce `foo`' do
    allow(Foo).to receive(:ask).and_yield('bar').and_yield('foo')
    expect(Foo).to receive(:ask).twice

    output = nil
    until output == 'foo'
      Foo.ask do |response|
        output = response
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this example, the test fails because `Foo.ask` is only called once since the logic in the test is satisfied after rspec yields the 2 values.  I need to test the block logic in addition to the `until` logic.  With `.and_return`, this works fine since it can only return one value per method call, but how can i get the same behavior with `.and_yield`?

Answer (score 1):

First, `and_return` doesn't behave as you appear to think it does. If `and_return` is invoked multiple times, the argument most recently passed applies, as demonstrated by the following, which passes:

```
describe 'and_return behavior' do
  it 'returns the last value specified' do
    dbl = double
    allow(dbl).to receive(:foo).and_return(1).and_return(2)
    expect(dbl.foo).to eq(2)
  end
end
```

There is a built-in way to tell `and_return` to return different values for successive calls, and that is to pass it multiple arguments, as described in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls

However, there is no built-in way to yield different values for successive calls to `and_yield`. In order to accomplish that, you need to provide your own implementation, as described in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation